# How can I use mean() in timeseries and drop it to columns?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have this problem:

```
bitcoin = pd.read_csv('./Bitcoin/BTC-USD.csv')
bitcoin
```

And then I have the values for the bitcoin for every day... But actually I want the average of every month in 2018 and 2019:

```
bitcoin['Date']=pd.to_datetime(bitcoin['Date'],format="%Y-%m-%d")

bitcoin = bitcoin[(bitcoin['Date']>'2018-01-01') & (bitcoin['Date']<'2020-01-01')]

bitcoin_mean =bitcoin['High'].groupby([bitcoin['Date'].dt.year,bitcoin['Date'].dt.month]).mean()

bitcoin_mean
```

[image]

Which is fine, but actually I want it in 3 different columns because I want to plot it, something like 'Year' , 'Day' and 'Averaged_price' in integers, how could I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could try `.transform('mean')` at the end of your groupby to get just the values back, which you can assign like bitcoin['mean'] = bitcoin['High'].gropuby(......).transform('mean)

Comment: use `stack(0)` and years will become columns

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
```

---

Lownload `BTC-USD.csv` from [here](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/history?p=BTC-USD), I also put it on [Github Gists](https://gist.github.com/zabop/0a3e9f1b8bfd7c101bbbf06c08c66d89).

Read in dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('BTC-USD.csv')
```

## Then you can get the average for every month:

```
df.groupby(df['Date'].apply(lambda row: row.split('-')[1])).mean()
```

which will give you:

[image]

(The first column is the months, 01 is January, 02 February, etc...)

---

### Why this works

`df['Date'].apply(lambda row: row.split('-')[1])` is a [series](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
0      08
1      08
2      08
3      08
4      08
       ..
362    08
363    08
364    08
365    08
366    08
Name: Date, Length: 367, dtype: object
```

It takes the date from each row, ie `2019-08-24`, [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)s it by `-`, so it gets a list: ['2019','08','24]. It takes the 1-indexed (ie second) element from that list, ie month. We [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) this variable & then take the mean() to compute mean of groups (search for `mean()` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)).